# Why does Email::Stuffer base64-encode differently than MIME::Base64 and how does utf8 fit in?

Tags: perl, email, utf-8, base64

I want to send a simple email with `Email::Stuffer`. As expected, it encodes headers with non-ascii characters as [encoded words](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047#section-2). But when when I decode them back (either in my mail client or in Perl), I get different text, and `MIME::Base64` encodes the same text differently to start with.

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Email::Stuffer;
use MIME::Base64;

my $text = 'Ümläut';
print "$text in base64: ", encode_base64($text, ''), "\n";
print "and back: ", decode_base64(encode_base64($text)), "\n";

my $stuffer = Email::Stuffer->subject($text);
my $dump = $stuffer->as_string();
print "Mail dump:\n---\n$dump\n---\n";

$dump =~ m{^Subject:\s*=\?UTF-8\?B\?(.+)\?=}m;
my $encoded = $1;
print "in Subject: $encoded\n";
my $decoded = decode_base64($encoded);
print "subject decoded: $decoded\n";
```

This prints:

```
Ümläut in base64: w5xtbMOkdXQ=
and back: Ümläut
Mail dump:
---
Date: Sat, 7 Oct 2023 16:31:59 -0500
MIME-Version: 1.0
Subject: =?UTF-8?B?w4PCnG1sw4PCpHV0?=


---
in Subject: w4PCnG1sw4PCpHV0
subject decoded: ÃmlÃ¤ut
```

(`echo "Ümläut" | base64` on the shell agrees with `MIME::Base64` and also prints w5xtbMOkdXQK)

The program source code is in utf8. When I add `use utf8;` after `use warnings;`, the first `print`s don't print the expected umlauts, but `Email::Stuffer` works as expected.

```
�ml�ut in base64: 3G1s5HV0
and back: �ml�ut
Mail dump:
---
Date: Sat, 7 Oct 2023 16:32:50 -0500
MIME-Version: 1.0
Subject: =?UTF-8?B?w5xtbMOkdXQ=?=


---
in Subject: w5xtbMOkdXQ=
subject decoded: Ümläut
```

What is the difference here / why does this happen and how can I get both `MIME::Base64` and `Email::Stuffer` to agree?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`->subject` expects text (decoded text, a string of Unicode Code Points).

`encode_base64` expects bytes (such as text encoded using UTF-8).

Fixed:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

use utf8;                               # Source code is encoded using UTF-8.
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';    # Terminal expects/provides UTF-8.

use Email::Stuffer qw( );
use Encode         qw( decode encode );
use MIME::Base64   qw( decode_base64 encode_base64 );

my $text_ucp = 'Ümläut';                # String of Unicode Code Points.
say $text_ucp;                          # Ümläut

my $text_utf8_base64 = encode_base64( encode( "UTF-8", $text_ucp ), '');
say $text_utf8_base64;                  # w5xtbMOkdXQ=

my $roundtrip_ucp = decode( "UTF-8", decode_base64( $text_utf8_base64 ) );
say $roundtrip_ucp;                     # Ümläut

my $stuffer = Email::Stuffer->subject( $text_ucp );
print $stuffer->as_string();            # =?UTF-8?B?w5xtbMOkdXQ=?=
```